# 404 on child page template

Tags: theme-development, 404-error, child-pages, template-hierarchy

I have a page called **portfolio** and I have created several child pages for it like **Video page, audio page** etc …

I also created custom page template for portfolio and named its file `portfolio-template-ahsan.php`. But when I use it on my child page as a custom template, it gives me the 404 error page.

Now what I am confused about is how this naming convention works, and how should I name the child custom page templates, if I remove the Parent page from Video page, then the template works fine, but when I use Portfolio page as parent page, it gives me 404 error

here is the code for the inner page template, could it be a problem if the parent page have different template and child page have different page template

```
<?php 
    /* 
Template Name: Portfolio template column four simran
*/
?>
<?php
get_header('ajax'); 
include('portfolio_loop.php');
get_footer(); 
?>
```

Comment: So far everything you described _should_ be working just fine. Any more details you can think of and provide? Maybe code of your template (leave unimportant parts out if there is a lot of it) ?

Comment: Can you add the (basic) code for that loop? It might be where your problem is.

Comment: Added the code for the portfolio_loop.php file, it was a theme i purchased from themeforest so i dont know much about its coding stuff

Answer (score 0):

If you're working with custom post types and keep getting 404 errors, you often just need to re-save your site's permalinks under Settings > Permalinks. Try that and let me know if it works.

Comment: No i tried setting permalinks many times, but strangely these page templates are working fine on my WAMP server installation